# Можно ли передать таблицу?

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно ли в mySQL передать таблицу, которую я создам у себя на компьютере, другому человеку, чтобы он её впоследствии у себя развернул и проверил мои запросы?

Comment: Плохо искали. Google -> `mysqldump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

да, можно. это называется «дамп таблицы»:

```
$ mysqldump -u пользователь -p имя-базы-данных имя-таблицы > файл
```